# Rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a rule that redirects all URLs of a certain pattern to a PHP file. Exception: the `control/` directory where the CMS resides.

Why does

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^control]+)/([^/]+)$   
RewriteRule .* /pages/index.php?language=%1&page=%2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

not work for

```
domain.com/deutsch/start
```

(it throws a 404), while

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^control]+)/([^/]+)/debug$   
RewriteRule .* /pages/index.php?language=%1&page=%2&page_debug=yes&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

works for

```
domain.com/deutsch/start/debug
```

?

Comment: what about %{REQUEST_URI} !^/control/ ?

Comment: Solved using a second condition as you described. (I'm not that great at mod_rewrite). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/control/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .* /pages/index.php?language=%1&page=%2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

But you should use your pattern directly in the `RewriteRule` directive if possible:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=control
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /pages/index.php?language=$1&page=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Another hint is to use the *QSA* flag instead of appending the query explicitly:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=control
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /pages/index.php?language=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, that worked. I had it worked out based on Aif's comment above but this is a great full-fledged answer for future generations.

Comment: Are the two latter ways preferable from a performance perspective?

Comment: @Pekka Gaier: The latter skip the test for `.*` to match.